# Left and right brace around different number of rows without tikzmark

Tags: align, arrays, braces

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc,tikzmark}
% \usetikzlibrary{external}
\newcommand*{\BraceAmplitude}{0.4em}
\newcommand*{\VerticalOffset}{1mm}
\newcommand*{\HorizontalOffset}{-1mm}
\NewDocumentCommand{\InsertLeftBrace}{%
    O{} % #1 = draw options
    O{\HorizontalOffset,\VerticalOffset} % #2 = optional brace shift options
    m   % #3 = top tikzmark
    m   % #4 = center tikzmark
    m   % #5 = bottom tikzmark
}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \coordinate (Brace Top)    at ($(#4 |- #3.north) + (#2)$);
      \coordinate (Brace Bottom) at ($(#4 |- #5.south) + (#2)$);
      \draw[decoration={brace, amplitude=\BraceAmplitude}, decorate, thick, draw=black, #1]
        (Brace Bottom) -- (Brace Top);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\InsertRightBrace}{%
    O{} % #1 = draw options
    O{\HorizontalOffset,\VerticalOffset} % #2 = optional brace shift options
    m   % #3 = top tikzmark
    m   % #4 = center tikzmark
    m   % #5 = bottom tikzmark
}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \coordinate (Brace Top)    at ($(#4 |- #3.north) + (#2)$);
      \coordinate (Brace Bottom) at ($(#4 |- #5.south) + (#2)$);
      \draw[decoration={brace, amplitude=\BraceAmplitude, mirror}, decorate, thick, draw=black, #1]
        (Brace Bottom) -- (Brace Top);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\tp}{\tikzmark{Top}}
\newcommand{\tc}{\tikzmark{Center}}
\newcommand{\tb}{\tikzmark{Bottom}}


\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\begin{document}

% \tikzexternalize % activate

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {a tikz picture};
\end{tikzpicture}

% \tikzexternaldisable % disable for tikzmark

\begin{equation*}
  \def\arraystretch{1.1}
  \begin{blockarray}{r@{\;}ccc}
    \mathcal{H} = & \BAmulticolumn{3}{c}{p2mg} \\[\jot]
    \begin{block}{r@{\;}[lll}
       & \vec{a}-\vec{b},2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{31} \tp \\[\jot]
       & \vec{a}+2\vec{b},-2\vec{a} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}' \\[\jot]
       & 2\vec{a}+\vec{b},2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}'' \\[\jot]
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{r@{\;}[lll}
       & \vec{a}-\vec{b},2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & 1,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}''' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{a}+2\vec{b},-2\vec{a} & -\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}'''' \\[\jot]
       & 2\vec{a}+\vec{b},2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},1 & = \mathcal{H}_{31}''''' \;\tc\tb%
       \InsertRightBrace{Top}{Center}{Bottom}\\[\jot]
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{r@{\;}[lll}
       & \vec{a}+\vec{b},-2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{32} \tp \\[\jot]
       & -\vec{a},-2\vec{a}-4\vec{b} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{b},-4\vec{a}-2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}'' \\[\jot]
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{r@{\;}[lll}
       & \vec{a}+\vec{b},-2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}''' \\[\jot]
       & -\vec{a},-2\vec{a}-4\vec{b} & -\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}'''' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{b},-4\vec{a}-2\vec{b} & -\frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{32}''''' \;\tc\tb%
       \InsertRightBrace{Top}{Center}{Bottom}\\[\jot]
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\end{equation*}

% \tikzexternalize % re-activate

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {another tikz picture};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Does someone know how to achieve this without using `tikzmark`?

I have a document which relies heavily on `tikzexternal` to have an acceptable compilation time and afaik, `tikzexternal` and `tikzmark` are incompatible.

**UPDATE**
I have added to the MWE commented lines to activate `tikzexternal`.
Uncommenting the lines with `\usetikzlibrary{external}`, `\tikzexternalize` and `\tikzexternaldisable` returns following errors:

```
demo-blkarray.tex|68 error| Package pgf Error: No shape named Center is known.
demo-blkarray.tex|68 error| Package pgf Error: No shape named Top is known.
demo-blkarray.tex|68 error| Package pgf Error: No shape named Center is known.
demo-blkarray.tex|68 error| Package pgf Error: No shape named Bottom is known.
demo-blkarray.tex|79 error| Package pgf Error: No shape named Center is known.
demo-blkarray.tex|79 error| Package pgf Error: No shape named Top is known.
demo-blkarray.tex|79 error| Package pgf Error: No shape named Center is known.
demo-blkarray.tex|79 error| Package pgf Error: No shape named Bottom is known.
```

Comment: `tikzmark` requires a double compilation. Have you compiled your document twice with `tikzmark`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I do not have a problem with `tikzmark` as long as I do not use `tikzexternal`.

Comment: Why not use a Tikz matrix?

Comment: Why do you think that tikz matrix is a good fit?

Comment: Yes, because its elements are nodes that can be used as points to trace what you want.

Comment: You could turn off externalisation just for tikzmarks. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Also, you should use the tikzmark library rather than that command.

Comment: @Loop Space: Yes, turning tikzmarks off for them would be perfectly fine. However, I struggled with this. Could you check out my updated MWE with the commented lines? Do you see something which I did not do correctly?

Comment: @LoopSpace: I also changed the code to use the command from the tikzmark lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very simple with package `bigdelim`. I took the opportunity to simplify a bit your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\usepackage{bigdelim}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \def\arraystretch{1.1}\setlength{\BAextrarowheight}{\jot}
  \begin{blockarray}{r@{\;}ccc@{\!}c}
    \mathcal{H} = & \BAmulticolumn{3}{c}{p2mg} \\
    \begin{block}{r@{\;}[lll@{\!}c}
       & \vec{a}-\vec{b},2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{31}& \rdelim\}{6.1}{0.5em} \\
       & \vec{a}+2\vec{b},-2\vec{a} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}' \\
       & 2\vec{a}+\vec{b},2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}'' \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{r@{\;}[lll@{\!}c}
       & \vec{a}-\vec{b},2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & 1,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}''' \\
       & \vec{a}+2\vec{b},-2\vec{a} & -\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}'''' \\
       & 2\vec{a}+\vec{b},2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},1 & = \mathcal{H}_{31}''''' \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{r@{\;}[lll@{\!}c}
       & \vec{a}+\vec{b},-2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{32} & \rdelim\}{6.1}{0.5em} \\
       & -\vec{a},-2\vec{a}-4\vec{b} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}' \\
       & \vec{b},-4\vec{a}-2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}'' \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{r@{\;}[lll@{\!}c}
       & \vec{a}+\vec{b},-2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}''' \\
       & -\vec{a},-2\vec{a}-4\vec{b} & -\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}'''' \\
       & \vec{b},-4\vec{a}-2\vec{b} & -\frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{32}''''' \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\end{equation*}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer which looks like the shortest solution to my problem.

Answer (score 5):

One can play around with the spacing a bit, but this does what you're after without a `tikzmark`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,amsmath}

\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbf}

\newlength{\firstlen}
\newlength{\secondlen}
\newlength{\thirdlen}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{$}p{#1}<{$}}
\settowidth{\firstlen}{$\vec{a} + \vec{b}, -2 \vec{a} + 2\vec{b}$}% Widest element in first column
\settowidth{\secondlen}{$-\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}$} % Widest element in second column
\settowidth{\thirdlen}{${}= \mathcal{H}_{32}'''''$} % Widest element in third column

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \mathcal{H} = & \makebox[20em]{p2mg} \\[\jot]
  & \begin{array}{ @{} l @{} }
    \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
      \begin{array}{ @{} l @{} }
        \left[\begin{array}{ P{\firstlen} P{\secondlen} P{\thirdlen} }
           \vec{a} -  \vec{b},  2\vec{a} + 2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2}, 0           & = \mathcal{H}_{31}   \\[\jot]
           \vec{a} + 2\vec{b}, -2\vec{a}            & 0, \frac{1}{2}           & = \mathcal{H}_{31}'  \\[\jot]
          2\vec{a} +  \vec{b},  2\vec{b}            & \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}''
        \end{array}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace \\[7\jot]
        \left[\begin{array}{ P{\firstlen} P{\secondlen} P{\thirdlen} }
           \vec{a} -  \vec{b},  2\vec{a} + 2\vec{b} & 1, \frac{1}{2}            & = \mathcal{H}_{31}'''   \\[\jot]
           \vec{a} + 2\vec{b}, -2\vec{a}            & -\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}''''  \\[\jot]
          2\vec{a} +  \vec{b},  2\vec{b}            & \frac{1}{2}, 1            & = \mathcal{H}_{31}'''''
        \end{array}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
      \end{array}
    \right\} \\[15\jot]
    \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
      \begin{array}{ @{} l @{} }
        \left[\begin{array}{ P{\firstlen} P{\secondlen} P{\thirdlen} }
           \vec{a} + \vec{b}, -2\vec{a} + 2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2}, 0           & = \mathcal{H}_{32}   \\[\jot]
          -\vec{a}, -2\vec{a} - 4\vec{b}           & 0, \frac{1}{2}           & = \mathcal{H}_{32}'  \\[\jot]
           \vec{b}, -4\vec{a} - 2\vec{b}           & \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}''
        \end{array}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace \\[7\jot]
        \left[\begin{array}{ P{\firstlen} P{\secondlen} P{\thirdlen} }
           \vec{a} + \vec{b}, -2\vec{a} + 2\vec{b} & 0, \frac{1}{2}             & = \mathcal{H}_{32}'''  \\[\jot]
          -\vec{a}, -2\vec{a} - 4\vec{b}           & -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}'''' \\[\jot]
           \vec{b}, -4\vec{a} - 2\vec{b}           & -\frac{1}{2}, 0            & = \mathcal{H}_{32}'''''
        \end{array}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
      \end{array}
    \right\}
  \end{array}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's working code with `tikzmark`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520211/86}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc,tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\newcommand*{\BraceAmplitude}{0.4em}
\newcommand*{\VerticalOffset}{1mm}
\newcommand*{\HorizontalOffset}{-1mm}
\NewDocumentCommand{\InsertLeftBrace}{%
    O{} % #1 = draw options
    O{\HorizontalOffset,\VerticalOffset} % #2 = optional brace shift options
    m   % #3 = top tikzmark
    m   % #4 = center tikzmark
    m   % #5 = bottom tikzmark
}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \coordinate (Brace Top)    at ($({pic cs:#4-\thetikzmarkbrace} |- {pic cs:#3-\thetikzmarkbrace}) + (#2)$);
      \coordinate (Brace Bottom) at ($({pic cs:#4-\thetikzmarkbrace} |- {pic cs:#5-\thetikzmarkbrace}) + (#2)$);
      \draw[decoration={brace, amplitude=\BraceAmplitude}, decorate, thick, draw=black, #1]
        (Brace Bottom) -- (Brace Top);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\InsertRightBrace}{%
    O{} % #1 = draw options
    O{\HorizontalOffset,\VerticalOffset} % #2 = optional brace shift options
    m   % #3 = top tikzmark
    m   % #4 = center tikzmark
    m   % #5 = bottom tikzmark
}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \coordinate (Brace Top)    at ($({pic cs:#4-\thetikzmarkbrace} |- {pic cs:#3-\thetikzmarkbrace}) + (#2)$);
      \coordinate (Brace Bottom) at ($({pic cs:#4-\thetikzmarkbrace} |- {pic cs:#5-\thetikzmarkbrace}) + (#2)$);
      \draw[decoration={brace, amplitude=\BraceAmplitude, mirror}, decorate, thick, draw=black, #1]
        (Brace Bottom) -- (Brace Top);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcounter{tikzmarkbrace}
\newcommand{\tp}{\stepcounter{tikzmarkbrace}\tikzmark{Top-\thetikzmarkbrace}}
\newcommand{\tc}{\tikzmark{Center-\thetikzmarkbrace}}
\newcommand{\tb}{\tikzmark{Bottom-\thetikzmarkbrace}}

\tikzexternalize % activate

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {a tikz picture};
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzexternaldisable % disable for tikzmark

\begin{equation*}
  \def\arraystretch{1.1}
  \begin{blockarray}{r@{\;}ccc}
    \mathcal{H} = & \BAmulticolumn{3}{c}{p2mg} \\[\jot]
    \begin{block}{r@{\;}[lll}
       & \vec{a}-\vec{b},2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{31} \tp \\[\jot]
       & \vec{a}+2\vec{b},-2\vec{a} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}' \\[\jot]
       & 2\vec{a}+\vec{b},2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}'' \\[\jot]
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{r@{\;}[lll}
       & \vec{a}-\vec{b},2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & 1,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}''' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{a}+2\vec{b},-2\vec{a} & -\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}'''' \\[\jot]
       & 2\vec{a}+\vec{b},2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},1 & = \mathcal{H}_{31}''''' \;\tc\tb%
       \InsertRightBrace{Top}{Center}{Bottom}\\[\jot]
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{r@{\;}[lll}
       & \vec{a}+\vec{b},-2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{32} \tp \\[\jot]
       & -\vec{a},-2\vec{a}-4\vec{b} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{b},-4\vec{a}-2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}'' \\[\jot]
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{r@{\;}[lll}
       & \vec{a}+\vec{b},-2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}''' \\[\jot]
       & -\vec{a},-2\vec{a}-4\vec{b} & -\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}'''' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{b},-4\vec{a}-2\vec{b} & -\frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{32}''''' \;\tc\tb%
       \InsertRightBrace{Top}{Center}{Bottom}\\[\jot]
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\end{equation*}

\tikzexternalize % re-activate

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {another tikz picture};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `\tikzmark` command has evolved considerably since the definition that you originally used, meaning that when using tikzmarks you have to use a different syntax.  That's what was causing all the errors that you saw, and with those errors then the externalisation wouldn't have worked for the other pictures.  Also, the command `\tikzexternalize` has to be in the preamble.

Another change is that the names used by tikzmark should now be unique through the document, so re-using generally doesn't work.  To counter this, I added a counter to your brace code.

The ends of the braces will be a bit off, this is because the new tikzmarks don't take up any space and don't define anchors.  Add a vertical shift to the upper end of the brace (probably `\baselineskip` would be best).

Incidentally, `tikzmark` and externalisation are incompatible because for a picture to be externalisable, it has to be contained within a definite box - both when being generated and when being included back in the main document.  Tikzmarks are for exactly when that doesn't happen.  I should probably add in a feature whereby externalisation is *automatically* turned off for tikzmarks since it makes no sense to even try to externalise a tikzmark.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, but the `OP` mentioned he needs the requirement without using `tikz`...

Comment: @MadyYuvi On this site we try to be as helpful as possible, which includes providing alternatives that may not fit the OP's precise specification but which are close enough that someone with essentially the same question might find useful. Also, if you read the comments on the main question you'll see that I did ask if this would be an acceptable solution before posting it.

Comment: @LoopSpace: Thank you for your answer. It was *definitely* helpful and I probably go with your answer even though I specified without tikzmark. I like the answer by Werner (which I had as a second try myself): but I usually want to avoid to  manually align things (defining the widest elements manually is necessary). The answer by MadyYuvi lost the alignment between blocks. I have to look into the answer by Bernard. I guess the size of bigdelim is also a manual value but probably less fragile than defining the widest element which can change more easily.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you, in this I used `mathtools` package only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\newcommand{\DeclareAutoPairedDelimiter}[3]{%Thanks to egreg for advising this
  \expandafter\DeclarePairedDelimiter\csname Auto\string#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\DeclareRobustCommand{\noexpand#1}{%
      \expandafter\noexpand\csname Auto\string#1\endcsname*}}%
  \x}

\DeclareAutoPairedDelimiter{\sar}{[}{.}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
  \def\arraystretch{1.1}
    \mathcal{H} &=\begin{array}{rlll}&\phantom{\vec{a}-\vec{b},2\vec{a}+2\vec{b}} &p2mg\end{array}\\
&\quad  \begin{rcases}
\sar{    \begin{array}{@{}rlll@{}}
       & \vec{a}-\vec{b},2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{31}  \\[\jot]
       & \vec{a}+2\vec{b},-2\vec{a} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}' \\[\jot]
       & 2\vec{a}+\vec{b},2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}'' \\[\jot]
    \end{array}}\\
\sar{    \begin{array}{@{}rlll@{}}
       & \vec{a}-\vec{b},2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & 1,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}''' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{a}+2\vec{b},-2\vec{a} & -\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}'''' \\[\jot]
       & 2\vec{a}+\vec{b},2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},1 & = \mathcal{H}_{31}''''' \;%
    \end{array}}
\end{rcases}\\
&\quad\begin{rcases}
\sar{    \begin{array}{@{}rlll@{}}
       & \vec{a}+\vec{b},-2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{32}  \\[\jot]
       & -\vec{a},-2\vec{a}-4\vec{b} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{b},-4\vec{a}-2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}'' \\[\jot]
    \end{array}}\\
\sar{    \begin{array}{@{}rlll@{}}
       & \vec{a}+\vec{b},-2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}''' \\[\jot]
       & -\vec{a},-2\vec{a}-4\vec{b} & -\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}'''' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{b},-4\vec{a}-2\vec{b} & -\frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{32}''''' \;%
    \end{array}}
\end{rcases}
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`. It's compatible with the processus of externalisation of Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tikzexternalenable

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {a tikz picture};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{equation*}
  \def\arraystretch{1.1}
  \begin{NiceArray}{r@{\;}ccl}
    \mathcal{H} = & \Block{1-3}{p2mg} \\[\jot]
       & \vec{a}-\vec{b},2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{31}  \\[\jot]
       & \vec{a}+2\vec{b},-2\vec{a} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}' \\[\jot]
       & 2\vec{a}+\vec{b},2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}'' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{a}-\vec{b},2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & 1,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}''' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{a}+2\vec{b},-2\vec{a} & -\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{31}'''' \\[\jot]
       & 2\vec{a}+\vec{b},2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},1 & = \mathcal{H}_{31}''''' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{a}+\vec{b},-2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{32}  \\[\jot]
       & -\vec{a},-2\vec{a}-4\vec{b} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{b},-4\vec{a}-2\vec{b} & \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}'' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{a}+\vec{b},-2\vec{a}+2\vec{b} & 0,\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}''' \\[\jot]
       & -\vec{a},-2\vec{a}-4\vec{b} & -\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2} & = \mathcal{H}_{32}'''' \\[\jot]
       & \vec{b},-4\vec{a}-2\vec{b} & -\frac{1}{2},0 & = \mathcal{H}_{32}''''' 
  \CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix{[}{2-2}{4-2}{.}
    \SubMatrix{[}{5-2}{7-2}{.}
    \SubMatrix{[}{8-2}{10-2}{.}
    \SubMatrix{[}{11-2}{13-2}{.}
    \SubMatrix{.}{2-4}{7-4}{\}}
    \SubMatrix{.}{8-4}{13-4}{\}}
  \end{NiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]